# Difference between [UIView beginAnimations:context:] and [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

It appears to me these two class methods are not interchangeable. I have a subview of UIView with the following code in the touchesBegan method:

```
if (!highlightView) {
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Highlight"]];
    self.highlightView = tempImageView;
    [tempImageView release];

    [self addSubview:highlightView];
}

highlightView.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
highlightView.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

When I touch the Button, the highlight fades in, like you would expect. When I touch up immediately (before the animation is finished), my touchesEnded gets called. This is the behavior I want.

But now, I've become a big fan of blocks and try to use them wherever possible. So I replaced the UIView animation code with this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    highlightView.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

Results: the highlight still fades in as expected, but if I touch up *before* the animation is finished, my touchesEnded does *not* get called. If I touch up *after* the animation is finished, my touchesEnded *does* get called. What's going on here?

Comment: Finger, sorry. Release = touch up

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new animation blocks in iOS 4 by default disable user interaction. You can pass in an option to allow views to respond to touches during animation using bit flags in conjunction with the `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion` method of `UIView` as such:

```
UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:options animations:^
{
    highlightView.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:nil];
```

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)

Comment: Just edited my answer — instead of an empty block I believe you can pass `nil` as the `completion:` parameter as well.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary any longer if you're building with iOS SDK 5, but I'm not entirely sure. I'll just leave my answer here for anyone still deploying for iOS 4.

Comment: So you're saying that the two are equivalent for iOS 5+?

Answer (score 3):

One more thing is that Appple doesn't recommend to use [UIView beginAnimations:context:], you can find it in `beginAnimations` [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations%3acontext%3a)

> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use
>   the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Probably Apple can mark old methods as deprecated in the future releases and won't support them, so using block-based methods is really more preferable way for performing animation.